# ETOPS between Johannesburg, South Africa, and Perth, Australia

Tags: etops

South African Airways flies over 6 000km across the Indian Ocean from Johannesburg, South Africa, to Perth in Australia.

I don't see any airports along the way in the event they need to divert.

Does anyone know what would happen in an emergency?

*PS Yes, yes, I know that ETOPS does NOT mean "Engines Turn Or Passengers Swim"!*

Answer (score 18):

ETOPS originally was an acronym for Extended Twin Operations. While it has been changed to just Extended Operations, the focus is still on twin engine aircraft. [South African Airways currently operates the route with an A340-300,](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/SAA280) which has four engines. If it has an engine failure, it is not as much of an emergency as in a twin-engine aircraft, so it does not necessarily have to adhere to the same ETOPS rules for alternates.

Johannesburg to Perth is certainly a fairly remote route. But at least eastbound it's less than 10 hours, and, for example, the A350 is certified for [370 minute ETOPS.](https://www.airbus.com/newsroom/press-releases/en/2014/10/easa-certifies-a350-xwb-for-up-to-370-minute-etops.html) This is 6 hours, and while that is at a one-engine cruise speed, it's still fairly close to covering the entire route.

[Looking at the Great Circle Mapper,](http://www.gcmap.com/mapui?P=PER-JNB%0D%0A&PC=red&DU=nm&SG=300&SU=kts&RS=best&RC=navy&E=240) a 240 minute ETOPS would be enough to fly the route with only a slight diversion from being direct. This is with 300kt diversion groundspeed. From the map, it appears that Mauritius and Cocos Island could serve as alternate towards the middle.

[image: 240 Minute ETOPS]